# scrollTo on all links

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I am using scrollTo on a page and want to have the functionality applied to all links. Shouldn't this code work? What am I forgetting here?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var target = $(this).attr('href');

        $('.scrollTo').scrollTo(target);

    });
</script>

<li><a class="scrollTo" href="#ref1">Recommendation for Developing and Disseminating Hazard and Exposure Data: The Integrated Tiered Testing and Assessment Approach</a></li>

<div id="ref1">
            <h3>REFERENCE 1. Recommendation for Developing and Disseminating Hazard and Exposure Data: The Integrated Tiered Testing and Assessment Approach</h3>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be more of what you're looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/wUs3u/ The line you need is

```
$('.scrollTo').click(function() {
  var target = $(this).attr('href');
  $.scrollTo(target);
});
```

Also, you should probably just use [HTML Anchors](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) for something like this.